# Clarification on SVM

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I have a data set with 7 observations and 2 dimensions. I have gone ahead and calculated the equation for the maximal marginal hyperplane which was relaying on 4 points, say z1,z2,z3, and z4. These four points are the support vectors of the maximal marginal hyperplane. My question is how does the number of dimensions affect the number of support vectors we will have. My original assumption was that it depended on the size of the margin of the maximal marginal hyperplane however from a lecture we were told the number of support vectors is j+1 where j is the number of dimensions we have. Is my original assumption correct? And if it is how would change the number of dimensions affect how many SVM's we have?

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: think about what a separating hyperplane is going to look like in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$. How many points *minimum* do you need to determine a unique hyperplane for **any** configuration of data points? Once you figure that out, it's pretty clear to see how the dimensionality of the data space affects the number of support vectors.